# PHP Extension VC Compilier Information Missing

Tags: php, c++, visual-studio-2012

When executing PHP with my custom extension module (PHP 5.5.30 TS non-debug/VC11 2012 V110) there is module information discrepancies with the VC11 version.

```
Module compiled with build ID=API20121212,TS
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20121212,TS,VC11
```

PHP:

```
Compiler    MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
```

PHP source being used is TS 5.5.30 compiled using VS2012 (v110).

Has anyone seen this before where no VC version is shown? if so, can anyone point me in the correct direction with PHP window build (specific to this VC information)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to taking time to look. After hours of search for the answer, it can be found here;

[Compiling a php extension with Visual Studio 2008, MODULE ID don't match with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641751/compiling-a-php-extension-with-visual-studio-2008-module-id-dont-match-with-ph)

```
#define PHP_COMPILER_ID "VC11"
```

This directive can be added in the config.w32.h file and it loads fine.

Thanks!